# Suggesting an edit on a 0-question but listed tag without the tag creation privilege triggers a server error

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits

I tried to suggest an edit on [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/429/last-element-of-a-struct-disappearing) where I added the tag `c`, which at that time existed (as in: was mentioned in [`/tags`](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tags) and offered as a completion), but had 0 questions. I do not have the privilege to create tags.

When I pressed the “Save Edits” button, the only feedback I received was the popup ”An error occurred submitting the edit.“ (and, consistently, the suggestion did not get through). A look at the Chrome console showed that https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/429/edit-submit/6afd6f04-622d-426f-a3f5-579d469d81ad 302-redirected to https://arduino.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/429/edit-submit/6afd6f04-622d-426f-a3f5-579d469d81ad which returned a 500 error.

Removing the `c` tag from my [suggested edit](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/314) allowed it to go through.

This would only happen on a tag with 0 question but not yet deleted by the nightly cleanup script: for an unlisted tag, the client blocks the submission.

Comment: It might be intentional to prevent repopulating tags that have been cleaned up that day.

Comment: @3ventic Sure, it's probably intentional that the edit is rejected. The bug is that there is a 500 error and an unhelpful message, rather than a message pointing the problem out. It took me a while to figure out what the problem was.

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't click on the links and apparently skipped the 500 error while reading.

Comment: @Joe No: that would refer to the tag on SO. I used `c` because I was referencing a tag name, not a tag.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: I wonder, once they split the MSO site to MSE, should [tag:blah] no longer actually be the real tag, but instead just be the way you refer to tags generically?  Or [tag(arduino):c] or somesuch?